# MariaDB 10.3.18 index not work "where (value 1, value2)" value1 > 2^32-1 value2 < 2^32-1

Tags: indexing, mariadb

```
SELECT `fn_ID` FROM `TABLE***` 
WHERE `fn_ID` IN (17982042765164298277,6595124129459942381) 
AND `is_pre` = 0 ORDER BY `fn_ID` DESC;
```

fn_ID is bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

but expain sql  the index is not work (fn_ID)

i tried the puzzle

```
where value1 > 2^32-1 and value2 > 2^32-1
```

it worked

Comment: Probably depends on what column type your `fn_ID` has ...

Comment: fn_ID is a "bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 "